# Problems on installing cvxopt

Tags: python, cvxopt

I am trying to install cvxopt on windows, I use a 2.7 Python Enthought distribution. I followed the instructions here,

http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/install/

The error I run into is the follows,

**./liblapack.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add o
ne
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status**

Please help me, I am pretty lost. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to get this running is by installing a pre-compiled binary.

First, download the [MLK build of numpy for windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). Then, download the [installer for cvxopt](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxopt) and run it.  It is very important you pick the build that corresponds to your version of Python.

The builds I linked are for the standard Python for Windows. They should work with Enthought's distribution as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Burhan for the prompt response. Sorry I am lost here, I don't need numpy, I already have it as part of the EPD distribution. What is causing the error you think. Ans is there a direct way to fix it, without changing my python installation?

Comment: Well numpy is a requirement, so if you already have it try downloading just the cvxopt installer from that website and running it. It _should_ work. To fix the error directly would mean setting up a complete development environment on your machine which is not practical nor necessary since someone has kindly compiled the library for you already on Windows.

Comment: What may be the interaction between MLK and Numpy from EPD, as far as I can tell, the EPD Numpy doesn't include MLK.

Comment: It does not (at least in the free version) according to [this](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/package-index/).

Comment: so how did you successfully get it working with EPD?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem too - it was something about gcc and stuff and I saw that there was some problem because of `-llapack` and `-lblas`. I then copy/paste `libblas.a` and `liblapack.a` to cvxopt-1.1.17 directory, to src directory, to c and python directory under src and so on and then it started working.